# Unity - Wait in MainMenu till Scene is completely loaded

Tags: asynchronous, unity-game-engine, scene

I have a little problem with my main menu in Unity.

If I press the "Play" Button, it starts the game how I want it to.

The problem is, that my scene "Lights" are not completely loaded. (I have a lot of effects in it). So the scene is loaded, but everything is dark, completely without the lights:

[image: My scene when run: no lights]

I tried it with asynchronous "LoadSceneAsync", like so:

```c#
public void LoadByIndex(int sceneIndex) {
    StartCoroutine(LoadNewScene(sceneIndex));
}

IEnumerator LoadNewScene(int sceneNumber) {
    AsyncOperation async = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneNumber);

    while (!async.isDone) {
        Debug.Log("hello");

        yield return 0;
    }  
}
```

Comment: That's not how coroutines work. `StartCorountine()` is a "do this, don't wait for it to finish, continue with the rest of the code."  Then your coroutine function just continuously logs "hello" to the console waiting for the async to complete. When it does, nothing else happens.

Comment: ok, thank u. But how would it work?

Comment: How would what work?

Comment: How could I load my whole Scene, before the game starts?

Comment: You already are. The fact that your lights are "missing" is likely due to something else. `LoadScene` and `LoadSceneAsync` don't "partially load" scenes. They fully load them.

Comment: But if I start my game manually, there is a Progress for „baking“ on the bottom right corner in the Unity IDE. After its finished, everything works fine. I think the baking process is the Problem.

Comment: "Baking" is for lighting yes, but it is *NOT* a runtime feature. It is, in fact, *explicitly paused* while the game is running. https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/LightMode-Baked.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it.

The problem was the Auto-Light-Baking.

Just go to Window > Lighting > Settings > Scene

And then scroll to the bottom and uncheck the "Auto Generate" for "Generate Lighting"